# Python subprocess.Popen terminates when stdin=PIPE is specified

Tags: windows, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm new to subprocesses in python, I need to spawn a number of independent subprocesses, keep them alive and pass commands into them. At first sight, subprocess library is what I'm looking for.

I've read the [documenations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for it and as I'm understanding to pass any command into the subprocess, I'd have to specify the input.

I need to run commands via windows command line, hence the toy example below is good enough that if I have it working, I'm pretty much done. Running code below via IDLE opens a new cmd window, printing a list of cwd files, however I can't write to it as stdin is not specified (would be writing to it using `p.stdin.write('DIR')` with `'DIR'` being an example command).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'DIR'])
```

Therefore I specify the stdin as PIPE, as per documentations.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'DIR'], stdin=PIPE)
```

However, running the second snippet of code instantly terminates the opened cmd window. Is that the expected behavior? As far as I could find in the documentations, only `p.kill()` or `p.terminate()` end the child process. If so, what are the possible workarounds? If not, what am I doing incorrectly, what other libraries should I be using? Thanks!

Comment: subprocess sets the child's standard handles via its `STARTUPINFO`. They have to be set as a triple -- `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, & `hStdError`. It tries to use the existing handles when not explicitly overriding them, but of course by default GUI pythonw.exe doesn't have valid standard handles. In this case, subprocess substitutes a pipe and closes its end. In your case CMD inherits closed pipes for standard output and error. Writing to either fails, and CMD immediately exits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would just like to clarify a few things. 

Why doesn't the first snippet of code (without `...,stdin=PIPE`) fail then? It prints output of the command to CMD. If I am overriding one of them, do I have to specify the other two as well?

As you said, child's handles are set via its `STARTUPINFO`. If I am only overriding `stdin=PIPE`, could I possibly get the other two standard handles for CMD? So that I could have input from python to CMD, but `stdout` and `stderr` would be printed to CMD itself.

Comment: Here's some background information. A process has 3 standard handle values -- StandardInput, StandardOutput, and StandardError. It also has a ConsoleHandle value. If a console executable such as cmd.exe doesn't inherit a valid ConsoleHandle, then by default it allocates a new console, and any `NULL` standard-handle value is updated with a console handle -- either for the console input buffer for StandardInput or the output buffer for StandardOutput and StandardError. `STARTUPINFO` allows overriding default standard-handle [non-]inheritance, but all 3 have to be set.

Comment: The first case works because it doesn't explicitly set the inherited standard handle values via `STARTUPINFO`, in which case CMD allocates a new console and sets all 3 standard-handle values to console handles.

Comment: One workaround is to call `SetStdHandle` in order to `NULL` all 3 of your current standard handles, and then call `AllocConsole` to get your own console window. Then when you override `stdin`,  `Popen` will succeed at duplicating inheritable handles for `stdout` and `stderr`, which will be handles for the console output buffer. CMD will inherit your ConsoleHandle, so it won't allocate a new console, and its inherited StandardOutput and StandardError handles will be valid for that console.

Comment: Another workaround is possible, but complicated. Allocate your own pipe via `fd_read, fd_write = os.pipe()`; get the handle for the read end via `msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd_read)`; make it inheritable via `SetHandleInformation` (via ctypes); create `si = STARTUPINFO()` and set `si.hStdInput` to the inheritable handle and the other two handles as as `None`; set `si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`; and call `p = Popen('cmd.exe /k dir', startupinfo=si, close_fds=False)`. The you can use `os.write(fd_write, b'some other command\r\n')` to send additional commands to the single CMD instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great clarification! Tried, calling `win32console.AllocConsole()` and only then calling `Popen(['cmd', '/K', 'DIR'], stdin = PIPE)`. pythonw.exe console didn't instantly close, also `DIR`output was written to console itself. However, calling `p.stdin.write('DIR')` still doesn't work as intended. Strangely enough when I call `p.stdin.write('echo hi')`,  `p.stdin.write('DIR')` or `p.communicate(input='echo hi')` no output is produced. When I call `p.communicate(input='DIR')` I get `More?` as output. Will have to browse through Stack Overflow for this behavior.

Comment: Also, are you referring to `SetStdHandle` from `win32api`? I tried using it, setting to `NULL`, but both arguments to `SetStdHandle` have be `int`. I tried setting the handles manually before calling `AllocConsole` and `Popen` like so: `win32api.SetStdHandle(-10, subprocess.STARTUPINFO.hStdInput)` as those were the `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` values given in `win32console`. However, doing that had no effect.

Comment: Disable buffering on Python's side and make sure to end lines with CRLF, e.g. `p = Popen('cmd.exe /k dir', stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0);` `p.stdin.write('echo hi\r\n')`.

Comment: As to clearing the standard handles before calling `AllocConsole`, the reason is that in some cases the existing handles may be invalid, but `AllocConsole` only replaces `NULL` handles values, so I just `NULL` them all beforehand. For example, `win32api.SetStdHandle(win32api.STD_INPUT_HANDLE, None)`. The `STD_*` constants (-10, -11, and -12) are accepted by some functions to use the corresponding standard handle value in the Process Parameters of the Process Environment Block (PEB) -- StandardInput, StandardOutput, and StandardError.

Comment: FYI, here's a short list of some functions I've tested that support the `STD_*` standard-handle constants: GetStdHandle, SetStdHandle, CloseHandle, DuplicateHandle, GetHandleInformation, SetHandleInformation, GetFileType, ReadFile, WriteFile, FlushFileBuffers, WaitForSingleObject[Ex], WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex], RegisterWaitForSingleObject, and SignalObjectAndWait. Note that for console handles, ReadFile and FlushFileBuffers only work with an input handle, and WriteFile only works with an output handle. Also, CloseHandle clears the standard-handle value in addition to closing the handle.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. I set all the handles to `None` via `win32api.SetStdHandle(win32api.STD_*_HANDLE, None)`, set `bufsize=0` and I can pass the new console window the commands that I need. However, how do I properly close it? I've tried `p.kill()`, `p.terminate()`, `p.stdin.write('exit \r\n')`, `p.communicate(input = 'exit \r\n')`. To my understanding, it only terminates the process while the console window isn't a part of it, only used for its `STD_OUT` and `STD_ERR`. Looked through `win32console` documentation, but found no function dedicated for that. Thanks again!!

Comment: If you don't want the console anymore, then call `FreeConsole`. The console host process (conhost.exe) keeps a list of all processes attached to it (for example, in order to send control events such as `CTRL_C_EVENT` and `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`). When the last process detaches (either by exiting or calling `FreeConsole`), then the console host will destroy the window and exit. Note that if the user manually closes the console, then all attached processes are notified via `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` and given 5 seconds to exit gracefully, after which they get terminated abruptly.

Comment: I've been playing around with it some more, because I need to have multiple console windows. To my understanding, I need multiple instances of conhost.exe to which different independent processes would be attached, however I had some issues figuring out how to spawn them and a 2nd console itself. Tried callng `AllocConsole()` multiple times, but that didn't work for some reason. I wish there was a more detailed documentation for `AllocConsole()` and whether it's meant to create a new conhost.exe or more specifically what it supposedly does as second call of it differs from the first.

Comment: Re-reading documentation for `subprocess`, I noticed `Popen` parameter `creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. After `AllocConsole()` call, I created a process like so `p1 = Popen(commands, stdin = PIPE, bufsize = 0, creationflags = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)` and it opened a new console window (via cmd.exe, not pythonw.exe). As I understand, `AllocConsole()` resets the `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and others to valid ones so that there'd be no issues with output/error, while creationflags creates an instance of conhost.exe? @eryksun, how do I upvote your comments? Can't have figured this out without you, thanks!

Comment: The process creation flags `DETACHED_PROCESS` (don't attach to a console), `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` (allocate and attach to a new console), and `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (allocate and attach to a new console that creates no window) are implemented by setting the child's inherited `ConsoleHandle` to respectively -1, -2, and -3. The process `ConsoleHandle` is the primary handle for the Windows console API, in addition to handles for the console's input and screen buffer. The process startup code looks to see whether a real console handle was inherited or if it's one of these pseudo-handle values.

Comment: If the parent process doesn't have a console, then the default behavior of a child console process is to create a new console. In this case, if you need to override the child's `StandardInput` as a pipe but let it set its `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` to the console screen buffer, then in its `STARTUPINFO` set `hStdInput` to the pipe handle and set `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` to `NULL`. `subprocess.Popen` doesn't handle this automatically, but it does allow you to do it manually with the `startupinfo` (a `STARTUPINFO` instance) and `close_fds` (pass as `False`) parameters.